# Angular change a value from a js object

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular and I have some data:

```
export class AppComponent {

data = [ 
    {
      "area1": {
        "format": "changethis"
    }
]
```

I want to create a method that will change the value of a key.
For example:

```
  changeKeyValue() {
    const key = data[0].area1.format;
    const value = 'someOtherValue';
    // Code to do the change here
  }

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `data[0].area1.format = <your new value>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update a specific item in the array, you can specify the index **data[0]** or **data[index]** and update it

```
data = [ 
    {
      "area1": {
        "format": "changethis"
      }
    }
]

let value = "New value"  
data[0].area1.format = value;

or

data[0].area1["format"] = value;
```

If you want to update all "format" attribute in your array, you can use any of the array method and iterate through it to update all values

eg

```
data.forEach(item=>item.area1.format = 'new text')
```